# Migrating ElasticSearch Java API FacetFilter (in early version) to simliar Aggregation in ES v5.5.3

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-5, facet, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am migrating a Grails application using Elasticsearch Java v0.93 to version 5.5.3. One of the challenges I am facing is to migrate [Facet Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/1.7/facet-filter.html) to a similar [Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/5.5/_bucket_aggregations.html).

Following is the code from the early version of Elasticsearch Java API:

```
FacetBuilders
    .termsFacet("f").field("brand").size(50) // Your facet
    .allTerms(true)
    .facetFilter( // Your filter here
        FilterBuilders.boolFilter()
    );
```

As per the Elasticsearch Java API "Facets has been removed and it is recommended to use [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) or [filters aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html).

Thanks!

Comment: It's been a while, but basically you want to get the 50 most common (brand) terms without a filter? That should be a straight forward [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

Comment: @xeraa what do you mean by without a filter? Also, `FilterBuilders.boolFilter()` has other `must` filters which I didn't mention in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below query to migrate `facets` to `Aggregation`

```
AggregationBuilders.filter("Filter By Some Property", QueryBuilders.termQuery("some Field", "value"))
            .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("Group By Some Other property").field("brand").size(50));
```

Here you can use any type of query in `filter` method. Have used `Term Query` just as an example.

Hope it helps!!